# adding a new version to the app store

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store

Recently my app `formwork inspector` made it to the app store.
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/formwork-inspector/id558300132?ls=1&mt=8
Now I want to add a new version of it, that is 1.1 so that means i will have to upload the binary again. After I add the binary, will my binary be reviewed all over again like the first time and once the 1.1 version is available, will it replace 1.0 or 1.0 will still be available on the app store after that? I dont want it to be available.

Answer (score 1):

You will create a new version in iTunes Connect for 1.1 and then upload the new 1.1 binary. It will then go through review just like 1.0 did. Upon approval it will replace 1.0 and 1.0 will not be available from the app store any longer.